# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout waterfall

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Could someone please guide me in how to create a "waterfall" layout. What I've so far created is below. But as you can see I want the spacing removed.

```
func createTwoColumnsLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                          heightDimension: .estimated(250))
    
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                          heightDimension: .estimated(250))
    
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 2)
    let spacing = CGFloat(10)
    group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.interGroupSpacing = spacing
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)

    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    return layout
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any solution? I have used CHTCollectionview

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of research, I actually found a layout that works. https://github.com/eeshishko/WaterfallTrueCompositionalLayout

To create waterfall/Pinterest layout you can create a single custom group and insert each item by its frame and index instead of providing a layout size.

You can view the outside border as the group and each column as the item:
[image: Image from https://www.kodeco.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest]

To create the group you to have to use `NSCollectionLayoutGroup.custom`. The custom group expects a `layoutSize` and a `itemProvider`. The size of the layout will be the whole collectionView.

**layoutSize:**

```
let groupLayoutSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .absolute(itemProvider.maxColumnHeight()) // the height calculation of the whole collectionView
        )
```

the itemProvider is of type: `NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItemProvider` which is a typealias for a closure that takes a `NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment` and returns an array of `NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem`.

```
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.custom(layoutSize: groupLayoutSize) { _ in
    // here we need to return an array of NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem
}
```

The calculation for the frame of each item will now determine the arrangement of each item in the group.

```
        var items = [NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem]()
        
        
        let itemProvider = LayoutBuilder( // responsible for the calculations of the watefall layout
            configuration: config,
            collectionWidth: enviroment.container.contentSize.width
        )
        
        for i in 0..<config.itemCountProvider() {
            let item = itemProvider.makeLayoutItem(for: i)
            items.append(item)
        }
```

makeLayoutItem:

```
func makeLayoutItem(for row: Int) -> NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem {
            let frame = frame(for: row)
            columnHeights[columnIndex()] = frame.maxY + interItemSpacing
            return NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem(frame: frame)
        }
```

frame:

```
func frame(for row: Int) -> CGRect {
        let width = columnWidth
        let height = itemHeightProvider(row, width)
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        let origin = itemOrigin(width: size.width)
        return CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
    }
```

config:

```
struct Configuration {
        public let columnCount: Int
        public let interItemSpacing: CGFloat
        public let sectionHorizontalSpacing: CGFloat
        public let contentInsetsReference: UIContentInsetsReference
        public let itemHeightProvider: ItemHeightProvider
        public let itemCountProvider: ItemCountProvider
            
        public init(
            columnCount: Int = 2,
            interItemSpacing: CGFloat = 8,
            sectionHorizontalSpacing: CGFloat = 0,
            contentInsetsReference: UIContentInsetsReference = .automatic,
            itemCountProvider: @escaping ItemCountProvider,
            itemHeightProvider: @escaping ItemHeightProvider
        ) {
            self.columnCount = columnCount
            self.interItemSpacing = interItemSpacing
            self.sectionHorizontalSpacing = sectionHorizontalSpacing * 2
            self.contentInsetsReference = contentInsetsReference
            self.itemCountProvider = itemCountProvider
            self.itemHeightProvider = itemHeightProvider
        }
    }
```

The only thing missing now is that we don't know the size of each item beforehand. The LayoutBuilder has to know the height of each item to calculate the frame. This can either be achieved by a delegate like https://www.kodeco.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest implemented or a closure like in this example:

`typealias ItemHeightProvider = (_ index: Int, _ itemWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat`

Now I can return the height of the image to the closure when I create the layout:

```
let layout = WaterfallTrueCompositionalLayout.makeLayoutSection(
            config: .init(
                columnCount: 2,
                interItemSpacing: 10,
                sectionHorizontalSpacing: sectionHorizontalSpacing,
                itemCountProvider:  {
                    return items.count
                },
                itemHeightProvider: { index, _ in
                    return items[index].image.size.height
                }),
            enviroment: env, sectionIndex: 1
        )
```

Since there is a lot more to cover I created a fully working demo project on github: https://github.com/vebbis321/WaterfallCompostionalLayout

Comment: The height has to be known before creating the layout?
    itemHeightProvider: { index, _ in
    return items[index].image.size.height})

This return some hardcoded height, will this work with Constraints with dynamic content?